# jQuery date picker no output

Tags: jquery, datepicker

**The code** if i run same code in separate file it runs.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: The snippet works fine, so I would presume there must be an error in your local version. Please check the console in browser devtools to see if there's an error you can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed the theme css libraries from the JQuery Datepicker:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Please take a look at the sample which is running perfectly:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker- Solution</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While the CSS is missing, the snippet in the question is clearly functional.